# What does "personnes racisés.e.s" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, société

> Une place s'est libérée dans notre coloc à Villejuif. Le loyer est de
>   452€ CC. On prioritarise les personnes **racisé.e.s** et LGBTI et on ne
>   peut prendre qu'un.e étudiant.e. (Demande de l'agence)
>  ⚠️ La
>   chambre n'est pas louée meublée ! 
>  Si intéressé.e.s venez dm
>   
>  RT appréciés
>
> ---
>
> A place was released in our roommate in Villejuif. The rent is 452 €
>   CC. Priority is given to **racialized** and LGBTI people and only one
>   student can be taken. (Agency request)
>  ⚠️ The room is not rented
>   furnished!
>  If interested, come on  
>  RT appreciated

*Google translate* tells me it means "Racialized persons" but that seems to not fit the context (a [tweet](https://twitter.com/lafleurdoran/status/1183743310223106048) asking for a room mate). Could you further explain what the meaning of *racisé(es)* is in context?

Comment: A definition of [*racisé*](https://liguedesdroits.ca/personne-racisee-racialisee/) on the site of  The *Ligue des droits et libertés* (Québec). I think we don't use the word much in France. If you go by the definition - which can be open to controversies -  I expect  in France a lot of people would say *personnes appartenant à une minorité* which in France  include LGBTQ+. It seems here it only refers to ethnic minorities and in France we would say *minorité ethniques*. Other opinions  needed

Comment: @laure the definition you give seems in line with the way I've seen the term used. I think it has gained momentum relatively recently at least in activist circles.

Comment: @sinopleincandescent your edit was perfect, merci.

Comment: Whatever the word may mean, that English translation is really, really bad. And Google translate is not at all reliable. racial exclusion or racialized exclusion (sociology). The advertisement was taken down by Twitter because it was poorly written and misunderstood. The tweeter meant:  exclusion raciale ou raciste.

Comment: As a side remark, as open it may seem (and I totally get it is an example of positive discrimination), this classified ad could be considered illegal.  I mean if you turn it upside down it becomes very obvious: "Priority is given to white and heterosexual people" is obviously illegal, in France and Belgium at least.

Comment: The "ized" in GoogleTranslate's "racialized" made me think of "stigmat**ized**" & of how, in this context, it could almost be seen as a truncated blend of "racially stigmatized [people/groups/'others']" which, regardless, is how I would (re)express in Eng. the meaning of  "racialized" in this context. NB, however, that the use of the literal rendering of "racially stigmatized" in French (ie, "[groupe/personne] racialement stigmatisé/e") is nearly nonexistent (but it is used in [this relevant essay](https://www.deuxiemepage.fr/2017/01/25/tribune-racisme-france-tabou-a-lire-entre-lignes/)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: someone who is a potential victim of racism, who is part of a group that is commonly discriminated against.

The long answer is difficult to write because this is a fairly recent expression, with a heavy cultural context. My answer is exclusively about France, I have no idea how or even whether this word is used elsewhere.

The word *[racisation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racisation)* was coined by French sociologist [Colette Guillaumin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colette_Guillaumin) in the early 1970s. (The first occurrence on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q="racisation"&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&start=30) is from 1978 but Google doesn't have the earliest uses.) It designates the sociological process by which certain people tend to find themselves victims of discrimination because they are members of a minority group. The concept is not limited to what is commonly called *race* in French or *race* in English today, which tends to focus on skin color.

The suffix *-ation* is a common noun formation suffix, starting from a verb ending in *-er*. The suffix *-iser* is a common verb formation suffix designating a transformation process of some kind. Thus *raciser* would be the process of transforming a social structure into one that involves a concept of *race*, and *racisation* would be the noun for this process. However, as far as I know, the noun *racisation* appeared before the verb *raciser* which hasn't really taken off. Given that the suffix *-ation* is very productive, this is unexceptional.

The adjective *racisé* (which would be the past participle of *raciser*) is a more recent addition to French. Its history is fairly well covered [in the French Wikipedia article on *racialisation*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racisation#Utilisation_politique_du_terme_%C2%AB_racis%C3%A9_%C2%BB_et_controverses). I think some activist groups started using it in the late 2000s or early 2010s, and it started to reach somewhat mainstream use in the late 2010s. To give an idea of its spread, the [Wiktionary article](https://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=racis%C3%A9&oldid=21460027) was created in July 2016, and the reference dictionary [*Le Petit Robert*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_Robert) [added it in its 2018 edition](https://bibliobs.nouvelobs.com/actualites/20180514.OBS6605/queer-antisysteme-et-rancongiciel-entrent-dans-le-dictionnaire.html).

Exactly which groups count as *racisé* depend on who you ask. Women don't: a woman who is a victim of racism would be *une femme racisée*. LGBT+ don't either, at least with most people who use the term. Groups that focus on certain specific discriminations may or may not get on with groups that focus on other discriminations.

The political context of *racisé* is that until 2017–2018, it was essentially only used by groups that have a racialized approach to discrimination issues: (certain) minorities must form autonomous groups that make their own struggle against the majority group. This is relatively unusual in the French political tradition. The history of struggle against discrimination in France is dominated by an egalitarian approach: I may look different, eat different food, have a different accent, but I'm a human being and a citizen just like you and you should treat me the same way, give me the same education, let me have the same jobs and live in the same places. [Positive discrimination](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/positive_discrimination) (which is how most French people perceive [affirmative action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action)) is not an established concept in France (apart from gender equality, and even that is recent). Minorities have traditionally sought integration, and left-wing political groups have traditionally promoted integration and joint struggle.

In the 2010s, there has been a rise of groups of minorities promoting a communitarian approach (*[communautariste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/communautariste)*). Such groups entered the news in 2017 with reports of meetings that were only open to members of certain visible minorities. This has met some backlash from other groups that defend the rights of minorities but oppose racial discrimination whether negative or positive. In 2017, using the word *racisé* labeled you as a member of a visible minority who rejected the French tradition of integration and promoted what many would consider as a racist approach, and labeled you as a political activist.

The connotations of the word are evolving rapidly. In 2019, merely using it is not such a strong political marker as is was even two years ago. It's entirely possible that the author of this tweet is not involved in politics. It's still an age marker; I suspect that it's fairly common among people who are students in the late 2010s but a lot less common among older people.

Comment: What is a racialized approach to non-discrimination? What is positive discrimination? The definition by that French sociologist would be exactly the same thing in English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racialization

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, that sentence was weird. I've reformulated the paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

*Racisé* is an activist term that is not commonly used in France and subject to controversies. Google translate gives a word for word translation into English and the English word "racialized" might be more used in the US than *racisé* in France.
The [definition of racisé](https://liguedesdroits.ca/personne-racisee-racialisee/) given by the *Ligue des droits et libertés* (Quebec Civil Liberties Union) says a person *racisée* is someone who is discriminated against because of their race, gender or religion. But obviously in this add it only means people discriminated by race since they feel the need to differentiate "*racisé*" and "LGBTI". A better way to word it would have been to write *personnes appartenant à une minorité ethnique ou LGBTI*.

Comment: racilaized is most definitely not used in the US, except to mean to make something a racial issue. And Villejuif is in France, outside of Paris, and the place is for rent in euros. Do you mean: discriminated against? Apparently, it has been deleted but you can still see it here, if you scroll down the page: https://twitter.com/dontdierobb?lang=en

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for pointing out about my misuse of discrimnated. Is it better now? I've toned down about the US, but I have met the word a lot more in Am. texts than in French texts. I do not understand your remark about Villejuif being in France... Of course it is in  France near Paris and I expect the OP knows, there's no need to specify it in the question.

Comment: Excuse me, Laure. The word racialized is not often used in American English. And when it is, it is usually sociological. As in racialized crime control, for example. Pesonally, I have never seen it except to mean something that is made into a racial issue, and very rarely at that. It would never, ever be used in an ad. https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/usappblog/2018/06/15/why-the-racialization-of-american-politics-is-here-to-stay/ racialized politics. And I expect the same usage in sociology in France.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think saying "it might be more used in the US" means it is  "often used",  it only means *racisé* is less used in French than "racialized" in the US.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I live in the US, I do tons of reading, and I have only ever seen it in very specialized type texts just as I would expect to see it in similar French texts: https://laviedesidees.fr/Race-et-intersectionnalite.html groupes racisés, for example. There is no reason to believe it is more frequent in the US except for the fact the US is much bigger than France and has problably done more formal studies on racialized issues due to having more institutions quantitatively speaking. I see no problem using it like that.

Comment: I don't think *racialized* is used in the US in the sense of the French *racisé*. In France, *racisé* does not include gender (and many feminist and LGBT groups have accused groups that use “*racisé*” of not caring about gender discrimination, and vice versa). “*Minorité ethnique*” is not quite synonymous and has very different usage; using one or the other is a political and age marker.

Comment: I just gave you a text from the College de France containing groupes racisés. It corresponds to racialized. The College de France text means: racialized groups. I fail to see where either is controversial or unclear. It describes a social/societal issue, it is not a naming practice. Read this text on race and intersectionality in French by French intellectuals: https://laviedesidees.fr/Race-et-intersectionnalite.html The racialization of groupes is racist, the term racialized is not. Gees.

Comment: @Gilles I am not discussing the English meaning, I only say about the word being used or not. Google gave the OP the translation, I say I would not have used it.

Comment: The person who wrote the ad did not do a good job of it. That's all. Of course, one would use something like: personnes exclues ou marginalisées par le racisme, but that is much longer.

Comment: @Lambie I invite you to read my answer, especially if you don't currently live in France. The connotations of the word have changed significantly in the past couple of years.

Comment: The supposed controversy was about the meaning: personne racisé would be a person who is the victim of racism. I see nothing controversial about that. The Canadians seem to be more advanced than us (French or American): Recognizing that race is a social construct, the Commission describes people as “racialized person” or “racialized group” instead of the more outdated and inaccurate terms “racial minority”. “visible minority”, “person of colour” or “non-White”. http://www.ohrc.on.ca/en/racial-discrimination-race-and-racism-fact-sheet

Answer (score 1):

This word is obtained from the word "racisation". Following the [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/racis%C3%A9) three senses can be found for it. A short explanation of the relevant one (2.) is given below.

In this particular case where essentially skin colour is not  in question (those LGBT people for whom the add is intended could be of any racial group), "racisé" means "treated by at least one part of the community (social system and/or population) as if constituting a race, and at that, a race not well integrated in the system, rather rejected". In other words these groups of people qualified as "racisés" are made to suffer in a similar way as that caused by what's been known for a long time as plain racism.

The Following opinion about this new term (racisation, racisé) is interesting ([encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racisation)).

- Sarah-Jane Fouda, spécialiste de la communication et enseignante à l'université Paris-III Sorbonne-Nouvelle, classe le substantif « racisé » comme un élément de la « [novlangue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novlangue) » des « dévots de la race », qui l'emploient dans le cadre d'un discours où toute personne non-blanche est considérée comme étant, par essence, victime de racisme : « À l’origine, un concept sociologique, utile à l’étude du racisme structurel mais qui, une fois entré dans la novlangue ordinaire, brille de sa nouvelle indigence (...) De fait, dans sa nouvelle acception, le mot ne renvoie plus au processus de racisation mais réduit la personne à une identité fixe, à « l’être racisé.e ». Autrement dit, on ne se fait pas raciser, on est un ou une racisé.e ».

Comment: racialized exclusion or racial exclusion, yes. And yes, sociology, basically. Not for use in advertisements for roommates.

Comment: Mais les comportements racistes persistent, des formes les plus graves (agressions, contrôles au faciès, restrictions à l’accès au logement, à l’emploi, à la santé) aux micro-agressions quotidiennes (plaisanteries, regards), à première vue plus bénignes, mais qui maintiennent les **populations racisées** à distance, en position d’infériorité. Par exemple. https://laviedesidees.fr/Race-et-intersectionnalite.html **sociologie et compagnie**

Comment: @Lambie "Not for use in advertisements for roommates." – I don't agree with you, although I know that my opinions in that domain go against the grain : according to what I feel is right you should be free to dispose of your property as you see fit, have the right to choose whom  you are going to  advantage and whatever else, and along that line of thinking, you are allowed to go even a step further, and restrict the lot of the sollicited people in such an advertisement, to only LGBT people; this is counter current thinking , specially as then   tags such as "white only" are fully legitimate.

Comment: First, getting a roommate is not about "disposing of property". This is a rental. Of course, you can rent to whomever you like.  But I would not use the word racialized myself in an advertisement in AmE. It turns out that in Ontario, Canada, it is a politically correct word in fact. I learned that and posted the link above. And if you are "disposing of property" which means selling it, you can't restrict your sale to any particular group of people.

Comment: @Lambie No, I didnt mean "getting rid of property", but "dealing with property in a profitable way (renting, lifetime annuities)"; I guess some other word than "dispose" is needed. Also, concerning renting, I assumed the French principle that the tenant is considered as being an owner of whatever place he pays a rent for and as such he/she is requiresd to contract an insurance policy for the place.

Comment: This is now way off topic. The point is I never said people can't have the roommates they want. They can. You can allow anyone you chose to move in as a roommate. No one can force you to have a particular kind of roommate (in France or in the US). Anyway, this is a co-location, and the renters (co-locataires) can choose whomever they wish. Please don't make it as if I am saying something I am not saying.

Comment: @Lambie Well, this being so, why  not give them the means to use that freedom efficiently and mention in their adverts the kind of person they wish to deal with ?

Comment: We are back to the beginning on this. Of course, but not by saying "racialized", unless you are in Ontario or other Canadian areas/provinces.  The advertisement context was my only point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100205/discussion-between-lph-and-lambie).